# How to get singular value from a generator?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, python-3.6

I'm writing an app to monitor chicken deaths in a poultry farm and have the following code:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
deaths = (sum(cd.count) for cd in ChickenDeath.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.date(today.year, today.month, 1)))
print(deaths)
```

My problem is it just prints out `<generator object chickens_overview.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x110010678>` instead of the actual sum. I've tried `next(deaths)` as well however I just get the error `'int' object not iterable`. Is there another way to get the value from this generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be returning a generator at all here. The generator should be the input to the sum function.

At the moment, you're effectively creating a list of items, each of which is the "sum" of a single value. That's why you get the error about not iterable; it's `cd.count` that is not iterable, because it's a single value and you can't sum that.

I suspect what you meant was to sum all the counts:

```
deaths = sum(cd.count for cd in ChickenDeath.objects.filter(...))
```

but that is not the right thing to do. You should ask the database to do the sum for you:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
deaths = ChickenDeath.objects.filter(...).aggregate(total=Sum('count'))
print(deaths['total'])
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help Daniel! On a sidenote, why should I have the database do the sum and not Python? Is it more effecient that way or is there some other reason?

Comment: Yes, databases are optimised for exactly that kind of thing. And otherwise you're requesting lots of data from the db that you don't need.

Comment: Good to know Daniel, I'll keep it in mind moving forward. Thanks again!